# How to convert elements of NSMutableArray to NSString

Tags: iphone, cocoa

I have 1 NSMutableArray and I want to convert whatever data in array will be in NSString.
tell me code for that. Array is nothing but object of NSMutableArray class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how do you want to use that string.

One way to convert an object to a string is to call `-description` (or `-descriptionWithLocale:`) on that object. For `NSArray` (or `NSMutableArray`) -description method returns a string that represents the contents of the receiver, formatted as a property list. The result you'll get will also depend on how `-description` method implemented in objects in array.

Answer (score 15):

If you want only the elements of array then you can try componentsJoinedByString:. This method returns all the elements with separator string without other formatting info.

```
[array componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

Here "," is separator string.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on how you want your string.
One approach could be iterate through array and convert each element of it.

```
NSMutableString * result = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
for (NSObject * obj in array)
{
    [result appendString:[obj description]];
}
NSLog(@"The concatenated string is %@", result);
```

You can modify the above code based on item's class.

Below code will convert Array to string with commas and other information.

```
NSString * result = [array description];
```